# Apache proxying to Unicorn server times out, how to avoid?

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I have a [Teambox](http://teambox.com) installation running on [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/), and the latter sometimes times out after 30 seconds. The idea of this configuration would be for Apache to wait until the Unicorn master server sends a timeout, because if I'm not wrong, Unicorn will quit the timed-out worker process but spawn a new one to handle the same request.

Is there a way to configure Apache to not timeout like the nginx configuration of `timeout = 0`?

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**

I found a way, though it doesn't really work as I expected. In the `ProxyPass` directive you have to specify a `retry=0` option after the url:

```
ProxyPass / http://url/ retry=0
```

It doesn't work if the url is a `ProxyBalancer` though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **ProxyTimeout** option in Apache, which will allow you to increase the time that Apache will keep the proxy connection open.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout has more information about the option.

I guess it would be better to try and diagnose why the connection is timing out in the first place though.